# No signature of method: description() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [abcdefg]

Tags: jenkins, groovy, scripting

Need some help with a groovy script I'm running. I am trying to integrate this as a job in a Jenkins pipeline. The method in the script that it's failing on is:

```
private void blackduckTestJob(def blackduckTestJob){
    blackduckTestJob.with {
       description("This job runs dependency checks for the Java reference application using blackduck.")
        logRotator this.logRotator.getLogRotator()
        wrappers{
            preBuildCleanup()
            maskPasswords()
            credentialsBindings{
                usernamePassword('BLACKDUCK_USERNAME','BLACKDUCK_PASSWORD', this.service.getBlackduckCredentialsId())
            }
        }
        steps {
            copyArtifacts(this.getProjectFolder() + "/" + this.service.getComponentName() + "/${this.service.getComponentName()}_Application_Build") {
                buildSelector {
                    buildNumber('${B}')
                }
            }
            shell('''
            #!/bin/bash
            set +x
            chmod +x ./mvnw ; ./mvnw com.blackducksoftware.integration:hub-maven-plugin:2.0.2:build-bom -Dhub.url=${BLACKDUCK_URL} -Dhub.username=${BLACKDUCK_USERNAME} -Dhub.password=${BLACKDUCK_PASSWORD}''')
    }
}
}
```

The error I get is:

```
ERROR: (JavaMicroservicePipelineComponent.groovy, line 154) No signature of method: JavaMicroservicePipelineComponent.description() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [This job runs dependency checks for the Java reference application using blackduck.]
```

Finished: FAILURE

If anyone can provide any help or suggestions it would be very helpful!

Comment: @Marvin That is not going to help.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that `JavaMicroservicePipelineComponent` does not contain a `description(String)` method.  You are invoking that method which does not exist.

Comment: Hi Jeff, that is what I thought, except I have other methods in the script all using description() without any errors. It's is only when I came to add this blackduckTest did it throw an error about the method

Comment: It would surprise me if you have other places in your script that are invoking `description(String)` on an instance of `JavaMicroservicePipelineComponent`.  That method appears not to exist.

Comment: The error message kinda says it all like @JeffScottBrown said.  "No signature of method..."

Comment: Do you expect `blackduckTestJob` to be an instance of `JavaMicroservicePipelineComponent`?

Comment: Exactly, I want the vlackduckTestJob to be a job in the JavaMicroservicePipeline

Comment: "I want the vlackduckTestJob to be a job in the JavaMicroservicePipeline" - Does `JavaMicroservicePipeline` have a method named `description` in it which accepts a `String` parameter?